# what is exactly the fine-scale geometry of Euclidean space?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

I have learnt math for a while, but I really do not have impressions on the concept of fine-scale geometry of Euclidean space. I hope this is not a trivial question as it sounds like. Any comments would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you be more specific?

Comment: I wish I can. Maybe it is just a trivial question or I misunderstand something.